# Git push certain commits from branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-remote

I was creating `feature` branches and merging them with my `master` branch during development.

Now I need to push only certain `feature` branches to another remote, but they are all merged with my `master` (and other `feature` branches). What would be the best practice for that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

If you merged `master` into the `feature-branch`, revert the changes until one commit before the merge and create a new branch with `git checkout -b undo-merge`. Then use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) with either `--skip` to skip the merge commit or just apply all other commits after that.

Old answer

You most certainly did not delete the local branches, just check them out and push separately:

```
git branch -a  # lists all branches locally
git checkout feature-branch
git push origin feature-branch  # pushes this branch only to the remote "origin"
```

If you deleted them, you need to figure out the commit hash, (search the mearge with `git log` and then check out the hash, create a new branch and push it again:

```
git checkout "hash"
git checkout -b feature branch
...  # repeat above
```

hope this helps.

Comment: no, but feature-branch is merged with master and has all the commits that I don't want to be pushed to new remote

Comment: If you want to go back one commit before the merge, do git reset --hard commit_sha , this will reset you to the commit before the merge (you need to find the commit-hash with git log or git reflog. If you want to apply commits after that, reapply them each separately.

Answer (score 0):

In many workflows, once a `feature` branch has been merged back into `master` it is deleted. GitHub is probably the prime example of this. If you follow this school of thought, you would delete that and create a new feature branch for your next sprint.

If you really want to keep using the branch, then you will either have to rebase the `feature` branch on `master` or merge `master` into `feature` branch. I don't see any advantage to rebasing, which could be messy, so let's consider merging. You merged feature branch into master. Therefore master already has all the features from feature branch but the reverse is not true, i.e. feature branch is likely missing several features which have been introduced into master. To do the merge you would use this command:

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

You may have to resolve merge conflicts arising from new features in `master` which are not yet in the feature branch.

Now the `feature` branch is up to date with `master`, and you can keep using it if you wish. Personally, I would just leave feature branch where it is and create an entirely new feature branch. You can keep it around for a few sprints until you are sure that deleting it safe.